# Parse List<Object> on java beanutils.populate

Tags: java, list, servlets, hashmap

I'm new at java beanutils and i'm getting a really hard time to figure out how can i accomplish this.
I can get all fields from Html FORM, an populate with `beanutils.populate(Object, request.getParamterMap());`

All works, even fields mapped as "CustomClass someobj", i had a little trouble but with form input field nominate as "someobj.field" i can get its right.
Now i need to do a map as List listobj but i dont know how.
Tried in form name as `"listobj[].field", "listobj.[].field", "listobj.[]field", "listobj[][field]"`, but none of this work. I can do it manually via `setProperty("listobj",List<CustomClass>);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
For anyone with the same problem, what i did was:

In Html form

```
name="indexedListobj[listobj.id].field"
```

I'm using hibernate so my object are now `Set<CustomClass> listobj` instead of `List<CustomClass> listobj` to prevent collection exception.
What i did was to create another method for check an index against objects in Set, then, update object if exists, or append a new if not. like this:

```
public CustomClass getindexedListobj(int index) {
     CustomClass tmp = null;
     for(CustomClass o : this.listobj)
        if(o.getId() == index) {
          tmp = o;
          break;
        }
     if(tmp == null) {
       tmp = new CustomClass();
       this.listobj.add(tmp);
     }
   return tmp;
}
```